# MongoDb Date query with php doesn't work

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to get today's data from mongodb.

Here is a sample document:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("586a284a1f815b55608b456b"),
   "timestamp": "02/01/2017 03:45:36",
   "data": "29",
   "lat": "not available",
   "time": ISODate("2017-01-02T10:15:38.57Z") 
}
```

And here is the PHP code:

```
$query = array('time'=>array ('$gte'=>new mongoDate()));
$str = $collection->find($query);
foreach($str as $doc)
print_r($doc);
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm getting empty output.

Comment: `new mongoDate()` is current time, while the document contains some time in the past, which is not greater that or equal to it.

Comment: You are right. my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `greater than` and you have no datasets in the future, so there's nothing to be found.

I think that you're looking for [$lte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) `lesser than`, which will give you datasets from the past.

Answer (score 2):

You have a past date in the data and you are querying for the date greater than or equal to the current date i.e now or the future, which will be empty. 
You may need [$lte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/#op._S_lte) (less than or equal to) which makes your query :

```
$query = array('time'=>array ('$lte'=>new mongoDate()));
```